# UITableViewCell ContentView/BackgroundView or Inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hi I usually add a new view to `UITableViewCell`'s `ContentView` instead of inheritance. But lately I've been reading that its a good rule to keep the view hierarchy as flat as possible for smooth scrolling. (thats one tip of many).

Whats the basic rule here, is it overkill/good to create new TableViewCell types!?

Comment: as per my knowledge or can say i prefer to use custom TableViewCell types for each type of cell i want to display in tableviewcontroller